# Program that Runs Specific Regex Commands on Text Files?

Tags: regex, replace, cmd, automation

Every day I generate a massive .txt file containing the entries of "Net View /Domain:abc" for numerous parent and child domains.

Every day I run the same set of regular expression find & replace commands on that these text files.

I'd like to make an applet or droplet that does this for me so I won't have to manually-open and edit each text file by hand (even though the replacements happen via RegEx in my text editor).

Am open to using something third-party, if folks have a "go-to" automated regex text processor. Thanks!

Comment: Assuming you're looking for something to run on Windows then chances are that [PowerShell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell) is already installed on your system. Then you can do things like for example `Get-Content -path "test.txt" | % { $_ -Replace '(\d+)', '$1.0' } |  Out-File "result.txt"`.

Comment: dbenham wrote [jrepl.bat](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044), which should do exactly what you want.

Comment: Thank you both for your time, and for the guidance!